# Galaxy S5 isn't getting any notifications but WhatsApp messages

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 Device running Android Lollipop 5.0.

Recently I've noticed that I'm no longer getting any notifications, but WhatsApp messages, which causes me to miss important emails from my work place, and from my boss.

It is very irritating, and I don't know what I can do in order to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off notifications for whatsapp go into settings -> application manger -> Whats App -> Then uncheck the box at the top that says show notifications. If you are using gmail click the side bar -> click settings -> click you account -> check notifications. Hope i helped and good luck!!